# Generator without yield

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```
var A = {
  demo : function() * {
    /* Some logic here, but no yield is used */
  } 
}
```

What is the use of a `generator` method that does not `yield` anything?
Have you ever used something like this? What was the use case?

Comment: Maybe whatever calls `demo` expects an iterator to be returned. A generator function is a simple way to create an iterator.

Comment: Yes that's a good use case. Have you ever used for any other cases?

Comment: @FelixKling If you want you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's quite the same case like an empty function - someone wants to call a function, but you have nothing to do.

Similarly, an empty generator function is a function which creates a generator that does nothing. It does represent the empty sequence. However, a generator function that doesn't `yield` isn't necessarily empty - it can still do something and have a result value, but there simply are no intermediate results.

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints 'someValue' on the response every 100 ms for 5 seconds. It does not use `yield`.

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const through = require('through');


(new Koa()).use(function *(){
  const tr = through();
  setInterval(() => tr.write('someValue\n'), 100);
  setTimeout(tr.end, 5000);
  this.body = tr;
}).listen(3003, () => {});
```

Access with: `curl localhost:3003`